# rails access records from a sub related model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Simple task which I don't know an answer to:

I have 3 models: Topic, Page and Subpage

```
topics   has_many pages
pages    has_many subpages
pages    belongs_to topics
subpages belongs_to pages
```

I look for the topic, based on the URL slug:

```
@topic = Topic.find_by_slug(params[:topic])
```

Now I want to access all subpages that are related to topics, so in fact I want to "skip" the pages.

```
@subpages = Subpage.where(topic => @topic)
```

How does that query look like?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare your relations with a 'through':

```
Subpage
  belongs_to :page
  has_one :topic, through: :page

Page
  has_many :subpages
  belongs_to :topic

Topic
  has_many :pages
  has_many :subpages, through: :pages
```

Then includes it and put a condition on it:

```
Subpage.includes(:topic).where(topics: { title: 'Hello World!' })
```

**In your case**:

```
@subpages = Subpage.includes(:topic).where(topics: { id: @topic.id })
```

---

**For the record**, you have to use the relation's name in the `.includes()` & `.joins()` methods, and we use the plural in the where clause (to match the table's name):

IF user belongs_to :post

```
User.includes(:post).where(posts: { title: 'Post #1' })
                 #^ No plural #^ Always use the plural in the where clause
```

IF user has_many :posts

```
User.includes(:posts).where(posts: { title: 'Post #1' })
                 #^^ Plural because has_many :posts
```

Comment: But a subpage belongs_to pages and does not have many pages. Its a 1:n association not n:n.